# Loading long RTF-Text in TRichEdit does not work

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

If a long RTF-sequenz (eg 150 000 chars) is streamed into a `TRichEdit` control (in XE4), the control does not display the text but instead shows the raw RTF code:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0...
```

What is wrong?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    RtfText: string;
    Stream: TStringStream;
begin
    RtfText := GenerateRtfText();

    Stream := TStringStream.Create(RtfText);
    try
        RichEdit2.PlainText := False;
        RichEdit2.Lines.LoadFromStream(Stream); //<--- ERROR: RichEdit displays raw RTF-Code
                                                //     if RtfText is too long
        if StartsText('{\rtf', RichEdit2.Lines.Text) then
        begin
            ShowMessage('Oh no, not converted!');
            //WORKAROUND: 2nd try seems to work...
            //Stream.Position := 0;
            //RichEdit2.Lines.LoadFromStream(Stream);
        end;
    finally
        Stream.Free;
    end;
end;
```

For instance with following RTF generation function:

```
function TForm1.GenerateRtfText: string;
var
    I: Integer;
    Stream: TStringStream;
const
    DOES_WORK_COUNT = 10000;
    DOES_NOT_WORK_COUNT = 15000;
begin
    //Fill
    RichEdit1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
    try
        //for I := 0 to DOES_WORK_COUNT do
        for I := 0 to DOES_NOT_WORK_COUNT do
          RichEdit1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(I));
    finally
        RichEdit1.Lines.EndUpdate;
    end;
    //Convert to RTF
    Stream := TStringStream.Create;
    try
        RichEdit1.Lines.SaveToStream(Stream);
        Result := Stream.DataString;
    finally
        Stream.Free;
    end;
end;
```

**Edited: Even copy and paste does not work correctly:**

This is what I did:

- I copied the generated content of RichEdit1 (lines 1..15000 with numbers 1..15000) into notpad.exe to remove any RTF
- I copied the content of notepad into RichEdit2

Result:

- only 12773 lines are displayed correctly. The last line is only `12`
- if I try to add another char into the TRichEdit nothing happens
- if I remove 10 chars (per backspace) I can add exactly 10 chars afterwards...

Is there a hidden character limit for TRichEdit?

Comment: So it works ok for shorter rtf? Make sure `RichEdit2.PlainText := False;`  before you load.

Comment: try setting up your stream position to beginning, by calling Stream.Seek(soFromBeginning ) before loading it up to your RichEdit2 control

Comment: @AlexK. Exactly! With the example code above it works ok for 10,000 lines but does not work with 15,000 lines. `RichEdit2.PlainText` is `False`, should have mentioned that --> edited.

Comment: @RBA Calling `Stream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);` before loading, makes no difference.

Comment: Does it render in another app? E.g. wordpad?

Comment: @AlexK. I do not think it has something to do with the generated RTF. See my update about copy and paste.

Comment: Can anybody reproduce this: New VCL application, add a button and two richedits to the form, add the two functions above, run and press the button. I get the error message. My system is Win10 with Delphi XE4.

Comment: @AlexK. `RichEdit1.Lines.SaveToFile('C:\test\test.rtf')` and opening with wordpad works fine.

Comment: I can reproduce this with Delphi 2006 on Win10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rich edit control has a text limit.

Try using [`EM_EXLIMITTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb788003(v=vs.85).aspx) message, which sets an upper limit to the amount of text the user can type or paste into a rich edit control. This message also limit the amount of text that you can stream into a rich edit control when streaming RTF (`PlainText = False`). but does not limit the control when streaming plain text.

e.g.:

```
const
  RE_MAX_TEXT_SIZE = 256000;

SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_EXLIMITTEXT, 0, RE_MAX_TEXT_SIZE);
```

or:

```
SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_EXLIMITTEXT, 0, $7FFFFFF0);
```

for the maximum limit as implemented in `TRichEditStrings.LoadFromFile()`: `RichEdit.DoSetMaxLength($7FFFFFF0);` 
However, `DoSetMaxLength()` is *not correctly* used in the sources, as it should be called *before* the stream is loaded. Also, `DoSetMaxLength()` is not used at all for `TRichEditStrings.LoadFromStream()`. Remy [mentioned this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43679369/loading-long-rtf-text-in-trichedit-does-not-work/43684370#comment74423062_43684409) in the comments of his answers.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb788003(v=vs.85).aspx): 
"*The text limit set by the `EM_EXLIMITTEXT` message does not limit the amount of text that you can stream into a rich edit control using the `EM_STREAMIN` message with `lParam` set to `SF_TEXT`. However, it does limit the amount of text that you can stream into a rich edit control using the `EM_STREAMIN` message with `lParam` set to `SF_RTF`.*" `LoadFromStream()` uses `EM_STREAMIN` internally.

Comment: Yes, and `TRichEditStrings.LoadFromStream` sets lparam to `SF_RTF` when loading RTF from stream. `"it **does** limit the amount of text that you can stream into a rich edit control using the EM_STREAMIN message with lParam set to SF_RTF"`

Comment: Calling `SendMessage(RichEdit2.Handle, EM_EXLIMITTEXT, 0, $7FFFFFF0)` before `RichEdit2.Lines.LoadFromStream(Stream)` solves the problems indeed. Thank you.

Comment: @yonojoy, Welcome. You better call it when the control is created (once it has a valid handle)  because it also affect user input/paste.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what kobik said:

`TRichEdit.Lines.LoadFromStream()` uses [`EM_STREAMIN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774302.aspx) internally.  When `TRichEdit.PlainText` is false, `LoadFromStream()` will first try to load the stream data as RTF, and if any error is encountered than it will re-load the stream data as plain text instead.  That is why you see the raw RTF code appear.

RTF is an ASCII-based format, and so `LoadFromStream()` expects 8-bit RTF data (and in the case of `PlainText=True`, will try to convert it to Unicode).  Try using `AnsiString` and `TMemoryStream` instead of `(Unicode)String` and `TStringStream` for your RTF stream.

```
type
  TReadOnlyMemoryBufferStream = class(TCustomMemoryStream)
  public
    constructor Create(APtr: Pointer; ASize: NativeInt);
    function Write(const Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint; override;
  end;

constructor TReadOnlyMemoryBufferStream.Create(APtr: Pointer; ASize: NativeInt);
begin
  inherited Create;
  SetPointer(APtr, ASize);
end;

function TReadOnlyMemoryBufferStream.Write(const Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint;
begin
  Result := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  RtfText: AnsiString;
  Stream: TReadOnlyMemoryBufferStream;
begin
  RtfText := GenerateRtfText();

  Stream := TReadOnlyMemoryBufferStream.Create(PAnsiChar(RtfText), Length(RtfText));
  try
    RichEdit2.PlainText := False;
    RichEdit2.Lines.LoadFromStream(Stream);
    ...
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;

function TForm1.GenerateRtfText: AnsiString;
var
  I: Integer;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
const
  DOES_WORK_COUNT = 10000;
  DOES_NOT_WORK_COUNT = 15000;
begin
  //Fill
  RichEdit1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  try
    //for I := 0 to DOES_WORK_COUNT do
    for I := 0 to DOES_NOT_WORK_COUNT do
      RichEdit1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(I));
  finally
    RichEdit1.Lines.EndUpdate;
  end;

  //Convert to RTF
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    RichEdit1.PlainText := False;
    RichEdit1.Lines.SaveToStream(Stream);
    SetString(Result, PAnsiChar(Stream.Memory), Stream.Size);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanx for the explanation. And at the end of `TRichEditStrings.LoadFromStream` a `EM_EXLIMITTEXT` message is sent, setting the limit to `$7FFFFFF0`. This explains, why the second try (workaround) works. But what could be the reasoning to call `SendMessage(Handle, EM_EXLIMITTEXT, 0, $7FFFFFF0)` after loading the stream? If I call this *before* `RichEdit2.Lines.LoadFromStream(Stream)` everything works fine.

Comment: "*at the end of `TRichEditStrings.LoadFromStream` a `EM_EXLIMITTEXT` message is sent*" - that was added in XE3. Prior to that, only `LoadFromFile()` would send `EM_EXLIMITTEXT`, but it would also send it after loading the file (via `LoadFromStream()`). So whoever was responsible for maintaining `TRichEdit` at the time clearly didn't understand how `EM_EXLIMITTEXT` actually works.  I would suggest filing a bug report if this still exists in recent Delphi versions.

Comment: I don't have Berlin or Tokyo installed, but I do have Seattle, and the bug exists in that version.

Comment: I filed a bug report: [RSP-18000 TRichEdit.LoadFrom...() sends EM_EXLIMITTEXT too late](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-18000).

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Actually this message should also be called once the control has a valid handle (e.g. `CreateWnd`) because it also affects user input/paste.